# OpenCV and JavaCV error : no jniopencv_core in java.library.path

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am new with `OpenCV` and `JavaCV`. I am trying to make a face detection program but when I run my code its showing below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:134)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:156)
    at javacvlearning.FaceDetection.main(FaceDetection.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javacpp10358349017844/libjniopencv_core.so: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:700)
    ... 9 more
```

I have added `-Djava.library.path="mydir/opencv-3.4.2/Build/lib"` to my VM agruments in eclipse. But still getting the error. And I am using `Linux` `Ubuntu` and
My imports are...

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvReleaseImage;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
```

Any suggestion how to solve this issue ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you loading the native library at the start of your program?

Comment: Yup, I have added native library....
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
.... Problem solved...actually I missed some .jar files in project libraries.